# Is a majority also a plurality?

Tags: vocabulary, semantics

I was thinking about the definitions of these two words:

- Majority: having more than anything else combined in a particular dataset. In other words, greater than 50 percent of the whole.
- Plurality: having the greatest amount relative to anything else in a dataset.

Because a majority has the greatest amount (it is number one in terms of ordering), that seems to make it a plurality. So, is a majority also a plurality because a majority has the greatest amount of something.

Note: Wikipedia says *It is also a plurality, which is defined as one group being greater than any other in the set.* I'd assume it is, but I just want to make sure.

Comment: In the case of U.S. Supreme Court opinions, the answer is no. An opinion that five or more of the nine justices sign is a **majority** opinion, not a plurality opinion. An opinion that (say) four justices sign—while one or two or three other justices sign a separate opinion concurring in the result but not accepting the reasoning of the first opinion, and while three or four justices dissent from the result itself—is a **plurality** opinion. In that case, the decision (the ruling in favor of one of the sides in the legal case) is a majority decision, but the opinion is a plurality opinion.

Comment: A majority is a type of plurality in the same way that a square is a type of rectangle. But you wouldn't normally refer to it as a plurality because the more specific term is available.